# Audit log without using inserted or delete tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need to set an audit log. I need a way to do it without using the *deleted* and *inserted* tables. I am using the SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

**Table A** (first records). Insurer and InsuranceResponsible are codes for the persons.

```
Id YearReview    Insurer   InsuranceResponsible    TicketNr  InsReviewId  ReviewDate Comment IdInsurance

124   2017        1496         2345                TK201705     1        2017-09-29    Test     234
119   2017        1567         4567                TK201608     2        2017-09-29    Axa      1024
45    2016        1567         4567                TK201608     1        2016-05-30    All      1024
```

**Table A** (*after some months*)**  note: yearReview and IdInsurance - it never happens for one year to have two same IdInsurance. So if someone does a review in the insurance for a particular IdInsurance it will erase the last record but it will always log the change. To be logged are: @Insurer, @InsuranceResponsible     , @TicketNr, @InsReviewId, @comment.

```
Id YearReview    Insurer   InsuranceResponsible    TicketNr  InsReviewId  ReviewDate Comment IdInsurance

521   2018       2456         1459                TK201805     1        2018-09-29    Ti       1274
520   2017       1496         2345                TK201608     3        2018-09-29    Remove   1024     
124   2017       1496         2345                TK201705     1        2017-09-29    Test     234
119   2017       1567         4567                TK201608     2        2017-09-29    Axa      1024
45    2016       1567         4567                TK201608     1        2016-05-30    All      1024
```

Table B - THE audit log Table - the header of the table was made by another person (i think oldvalue and newvalue are not good in a log table.. but now I must stick to these). I have not included here LastChangeUser neither LastChangeDate but they do exist.

```
    Id    AlteredField  OldValue  NewValue  IdInsurance  CreationDate CreationUser Event

    34        n/a          n/a      n/a      1024         2016-05-30      1567   'New Review 2016'
    45      'InsReview'     1       2        1024         2017-09-29      1567   'Review 2017'
    46  
    (...)

    1000      n/a          n/a      n/a      1274         2018-09-29      2456   'NewReview 2018'  
    1001    'InsReview'     2       3        1024         2018-09-29     1486  'Review 2018'
```

one possibility I am not sure to be right...

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdateTableLog] 
     @IdInsurance int
    ,@YearReview char(4)
    ,@Insurer int
    ,@InsuranceResponsible int
    ,@TicketNr nvarchar(50)
    ,@InsReviewId int
    ,@comment nvarchar(255)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    DECLARE @OldInsurer int
    DECLARE @OldInsuranceResponsible int
    DECLARE @OldTicketNr nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @OldInsReviewId int
    DECLARE @OldComment nvarchar(255)


    -- SELECT OLD VALUES IN TABLE A 
    SET @OldInsurer = (SELECT TOP 1 [Insurer] from tableA WHERE Id = @IdInsurance and YearReview=@YearReview )
    SET @OldInsuranceResponsible = (SELECT TOP 1 [InsuranceResponsible] from tableA WHERE Id = @IdInsurance and YearReview=@YearReview )
    SET @OldTicketNr = (SELECT TOP 1 [TicketNr] from tableA WHERE Id = @IdInsurance and YearReview=@YearReview )
    SET @OldInsReviewId = (SELECT TOP 1 [InsReviewId] from tableA WHERE Id = @IdInsurance and YearReview=@YearReview  ) 
    SET @OldComment = (SELECT TOP 1 [Comment] from tableA WHERE Id = @IdInsurance and YearReview=@YearReview )
    SET @OldIdInsurance = (SELECT TOP 1 [IdInsurance] from tableA WHERE Id = @IdInsurance and YearReview=@YearReview )


    -- INSURER: EVALUATE IF SOMETHING HAS CHANGED
        IF @OldInsurer is not NULL

        BEGIN
        IF @OldInsReviewId <> @InsReviewId
                BEGIN 
                          INSERT INTO TableB ('InsReview',@OldInsReviewId,@InsReviewId,@IdInsurance,getdate(),@Insurer, concat('Review ' + year(getdate()) )
                    END

    same reasoning for the remaining 4.
        END

        ELSE   -- FOR the case where there are no lines in table B to compare, meaning a new review..

            BEGIN 
                  INSERT INTO TableB ('N/A','n/a','n/a',@IdInsurance,getdate(),@Insurer, concat('New Review ' + year(getdate()) )
            END
       END
```

So my questions are:

1) do you agree with the stored procedure designed to get the table B shown above?

2) Is it possible to achieve the same table B avoiding declaring variables and not using the inserted/deleted tables of SQL server 2012? Maybe not.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the `deleted` and `inserted` tables? Using them would make the code neater and *much* quicker.

Comment: I am only curious if there are other ways to do the same stuff. I suppose the sp I wrote here is ok?...

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but YearReview ought to be a smallint, and TicketNr an int to which 'TK' is prefixed.

Answer (score 1):

I have to recommend using [`deleted` and `inserted` with `UNPIVOT`](http://www.madeiradata.com/audit-changes-every-table-sql-server/) for this audit table pattern.  The question asks for how to do this without them...

The stored procedure in the question will do what you're trying to do.  The section where the old values are read can be improved.  The `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses are the same for all of the queries as they are reading the same row, so there ought to be one query.  In the old version the table is read repeatedly, which is bad for performance and puts load on the database slowing everything else down too.  It's not noticeable with small table, but with a few hundred million rows this sort of thing makes a big difference.  And, as we've already established that the Id, and YearReview are a unique key, the `TOP` operator is unnecessary.

So the `SELECT OLD VALUES IN TABLE A` would be better as:

```
SELECT 
  @OldInsurer = [Insurer]
, @OldInsuranceResponsible = [InsuranceResponsible]
, @OldTicketNr = [TicketNr]
, @OldInsReviewId = [InsReviewId]
, @OldComment = [Comment]
, @OldIdInsurance = [IdInsurance]
FROM tableA 
WHERE Id = @IdInsurance and YearReview=@YearReview
```